# Any way of stopping a view from failing if a column is deleted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

If I have a view that references 5 columns in a table, but one of them columns gets deleted or renamed - is there any way I can anticipate this so it doesn't stop the view from failing to be run?

Is the above possible?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some products prevent this problem, while others will fail.

Comment: Using SQL Server 2016

Comment: Setting `SCHEMABINDING` causes that a given object (view, function, etc.) is associated with all other objects referenced. So if the view uses a table then it cannot be changed or deleted because it would violate the structure of the view. Using `SCHEMABINDING` is a rigid association and prevents the accidental deletion of related objects.

Comment: Is the column alteration on purpose? if so then its that design/choice that needs to be questioned/challenged.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider creating your view `WITH SCHEMABINDING` as this will prevent changes to the underlying tables in the first place

[More Info](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4673/benefits-of-schemabinding-in-sql-server/)